# Minify SCSS Files and add it to angular.json file

Tags: sass, angular6

I have 10 scss files in src/scss folder like below, i want to minified those 10 scss files into single files and then include minified file in angular.json under styles array or src/styles.css,

for example,

src/scss

- 1.scss
- 2.scss
- 3.scss
- ...

in angular.json file

```
{
 "styles": [
  1.scss,
  2.scss
  3.scss
 ]
}
```

instead of,

```
{
 "styles": [
  example.min.css //all scss(1.scss, 2.scss, ...) files minified in single file
 ]
}
```

because if i not minified, the styles.js file get increased to 5.18MB, please refer below,

```
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 5.16 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

Could you tell me how to improve it?

Comment: Do those 10 scss files go up to your website? Normally you would compile them to CSS then include that one file. I dont know angular, but I cant see minifying scss files